# GMAIL Failing to render simple tables in email

Tags: html-table, gmail, rendering, html-email

Anyone who gets back to me on this is an absolute legend. I sincerely hope this is just a matter of being too close to the code and I am not able to see it any more. In most if not all browsers and email clients the code is rendering fine. But in GMAIL, the bottom table is blowing out the left and the content on the right hand side to the the right.

Here is a shot of it on litmus: https://betalondon.litmus.com/pub/dfe0bd6

And here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title>ENO MAGIC FLUTE e-mail</title>


</head>

<body>
<table align="center" bgcolor="#000000" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td align="center" valign="top">
    <table width="1030px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  border="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="140" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000" style="line-height: 0px;">
            </td>
            <td valign="top" width="600" bgcolor="#000000">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table height="135" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                        <tr>
                        <td  valign="middle" border="0">
                        <a href="http://www.eno.org"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/header2.jpg" alt="logo"  width="600" height="283" border="0"/></a>
                        </td>

                        <td  valign="bottom" border="0" width="18" height="15" bg-color="#ffffff">
                        <br/>
                        <br/>
                        </td>

                        </tr>
                    </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>




                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                            <tr>

                                <td width="310" valign="top">
                                <table cellpadding="0" width="300" cellspacing="4" border="0" style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 10px;">

                <!--Title text--><tr>
                                    <td align="left">
                                    <span style="text-decoration: uppercase; font-family:Helvetica, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:120%;">MOZART's<br/>
                                    </span>
                                    <span style="text-decoration: uppercase; font-family:Helvetica, Arial; font-size:25px; color:#000000; line-height:150%;"><strong>THE MAGIC FLUTE</strong></span><br/>
                                    <span style="text-decoration: uppercase; font-family:Helvetica, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:150%;">13 Sep - 18 Oct</span><br/>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>

                <!--Body-text--><td align="left">


<span style="font-family:Helvetica, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:120%;">
                                    You are invited back to witness the adventure, music and emotion of one of Mozart's most stirring operas, your last chance to witness Nicholas Hytner's lavish production.<br/><br/>

Its distinctive characters, Papageno, Pamina, Sarastro and The Queen of the Night, along with magical sets, costumes and fantasy creatures, make this remarkable opera one not to be missed. Catch one of the final ten performances for what's been considered <em>'one of ENO's most magical interpretations'</em> (The Times)<br/><br/>

This time why not share the enjoyment and bring friends and family. 
                                    </span>
<br/>
<br/>
       <table style="background:#e4e4e4; border: solid 1px #d7d7d7;">
    <tr>
        <td style="padding: 5px;">
<span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000; font-size: 18px;">
    Final 10 performances<br/>
    Tickets from £19<br/>
    Children under 16 half price<br/>
    <a href="http://www.eno.org/see-whats-on/productions/production-page.php?&itemid=2130" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/booknow.png" border="0"/></a>
</span>
       </td>
   </tr>
      </table>        
<br/>

                                   </td>

                                    </tr>


                                </tr>



                                </table>



                                <br/><br/>
<br/><br/>




                                </td>
                                <td><img src="http://content.high50.com/emails/20012012/images/1x1.gif" width="35" height="5" border="0" /></td>


                                <td valign="top">
                                    <br/>
                                <table width="255" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%">
                                <tr>
                                <td valign="top" width="280" align="left">

                                    <font style="font-family:arial; font-size:14px; color:#000000; line-height:1.5em; padding-left: 40px; margin-top: 15px;"><strong>BOX OFFICE: </strong></font><br/>
                                    <span style="font-family: arial; color: #ed1c24; font-size: 18px; padding-left: 40px;">020 7845 95300</span><br/>
                                    <span style="font-family: arial; "> 
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/englishnationalopera" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/fbook.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/E_N_O" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/twitter.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/englishnationalopera" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/youtube.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/eno-baylis/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/flickr.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="http://vimeo.com/englishnationalopera" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/vimeo.png" border="0"/></a>
                            </span>
                                    <br/>
                                    <br/>


<img style="padding-left: 11px;" src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/listen.png" border="0"/></a>
<br/>
<span style="font-family:Georgia, arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#999999; line-height:1.5em; font-style: italic; padding-left: 40px; float: left; text-decoration: none;">
    <a href="http://www.eno.org/see-whats-on/productions/production-page.php?itemid=2130&tab=audio" style="text-decoration:none; color: #999;"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/arrow.png" style="float: left;" align="left" border="0" hspace="3" valign="middle" border="0"/>Overture</a><br/>

                                  <a href="http://www.eno.org/see-whats-on/productions/production-page.php?itemid=2130&tab=audio" style="text-decoration:none; color: #999;"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/arrow.png" style="float: left;" align="left" border="0" hspace="3" valign="middle" border="0"/>Queen of the Night</a><br/>

                                  <a href="http://www.eno.org/see-whats-on/productions/production-page.php?itemid=2130&tab=audio" style="text-decoration:none; color: #999;"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/arrow.png" style="float: left;" align="left" border="0" hspace="3" valign="middle" border="0"/>Papagena and Papageno</a></span>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

</td>                                           
        </tr>
                            </table>

                                </td>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <table height="" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="600">
                        <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <hr style="width: 600px; color:#6493b1; border: dotted 1px;"/>
                            <a href="mailto:?Subject=Book tickets to see The Magic Flute&body=Shall we go and see this opera together?: You are invited back to witness the adventure, music and emotion of one of Mozart's most stirring operas, your last chance to witness Nicholas Hytner's lavish production. Book here
                            #[http://www.eno.org/see-whats-on/productions/production-page.php?selected_date=13-09-2012&itemid=2130]#"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/forward.png" alt="forward this e-mail to a friend" width="" height="" border="0"/></a>

                            <span style="float: right; font-family: arial;"><strong>FOLLOW US</strong>: 
                                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/englishnationalopera" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/fbook.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="https://twitter.com/E_N_O" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/twitter.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="http://www.youtube.com/englishnationalopera" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/youtube.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/eno-baylis/" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/flickr.png" border="0"/></a>
                                <a href="http://vimeo.com/englishnationalopera" target="_blank"><img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/vimeo.png" border="0"/></a>
                            </span>
<br/><br/>
                            <center><span style="text-align: center; font-family: arial; font-size: 20px;"><strong>ENGLISH NATIONAL OPERA</strong></span><br/><span style="text-align: center; font-family: arial; font-size: 12px;">London Coliseum, 38 St. Martin's Lane, London, WC2N 4ES BOX OFFICE: 020 78459300<br/><br/>
                            <img src="http://www.beta-testing.co.uk.php5-23.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/eno/artslottery.png" border="0"/><br/><br/>
                            ENO is a registered charity in England (no 257210)</span><br/><br/>
                    <span style="font-family: arial; font-size: 11px;">Photos: GTG/ Yunus Durukan</span>    <br/>
                            <hr style="border:1px dotted; color:#6493b1;"><br/><br/>
                        <a href="mailto:boxoffice@eno.org" style="font-family:arial; font-size:12px; color: #e41d2a; text-decoration:none; margin-top: 10px;">Unsubscribe</a></center>

                        </td>                   
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>   
                    <tr>
                        <td>

                        <table height="90" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"  width="600" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                        <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="center"> 

                        <br /><br />
                         <br />
                        </td>                   
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>       
                </table>
            </td>
            <td width="140" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000"></td>
        </tr>   
    </table>


    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is invalid. Use the [W3C validator service](http://validator.w3.org/check) to check it. Pay special attention to errors like this:

> Line 91, Column 37: end tag for "table" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was
>   specified

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked:

1- Open Firefox with Firebug

2- Go to gmail

3- Click "Compose"

4- Right click on the textfield, and choose "Inspect element with Firebug"

5- Search the following code:

```
[-] <iframe id=":jo" class="Am Al editable" frameborder="0" style="padding: 0px; height: 569.5px; background-color: white;" tabindex="1">
   [-] <html style="background:none transparent;min-width:0;">
      [+] <head>
      [+] <body id=":jo" class="editable LW-avf" style="min-width:0;" hidefocus="true" g_editable="true">
   </html>
</iframe>
```

6- Select `<body>` and click `Edit` button

7- Paste your code between `<body>` and `</body>` (not included).

8- Close firebug

9- Send the email.